# Removing "/jekyll/update" from the jekyll URLs

Tags: url, jekyll

I am trying to build a site using jekyll. Here is my config:

```
# Dependencies
markdown: redcarpet
pygments: true

# Permalinks
permalink:        /blog/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title/

# Setup
title:            Jekyll Metro
tagline:          'A Metro theme for Jekyell'
description:      'A Sample blog using JekyllMetro'
url:              http://blog-olakara.rhcloud.com

# Author Details
author:         'Abdel Raoof Olakara'


# Google Analytics
gahandler: 'UA-52149651-1'

# Blog Configurations
paginate: 5 # Posts per page on the blog index
paginate_path: "/blog/page:num"
destination: ./_site
navigation:
- text: Blog
  url: /blog/
- text: Archive
  url: /archive/
- text: About
  url: /about/

# Custom vars
version:          0.1.0
```

And here is my blog : http://blog-olakara.rhcloud.com/blog/ if I go to any post.. I get "/jekyll/update/"..

[image: screenshopt]

What I need is to avoid the display of jekyll/update in the path. what is the configuration mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The example post has two categories "jekyll" and "update" that are appended to url.
Try remove them.

You can also change your "permalink" pattern from :

```
permalink:        /blog/:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title/
```

to :

```
permalink:        /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/
```